# Change SQL Query update time

Tags: sql, database, view

I'm reasonably new to using SQL, so I apologise if this is a newbish question!

I'm wanting to be able to view the results of a query in a graph on my website. The problem however is the query takes 2-3 seconds to process (due to a Distinct count over 200,000+ fields), and could likely be called multiple times a second.

If I put the query in a view instead, and have my graph access the view, is there anyway I can set the view to update periodically instead of everytime someone goes to the site? Or is there another way round this?

EDIT: DBMS is MySQL

Comment: What `DBMS` are you using? you can cache the view result.

Comment: You should add some indexes on your table to improve speed.

Comment: Not very familiar with SQL-Server but have you looked at using an indexed view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could populate the data using a sproc or even just a normal TSQL if you want, using a [Scheduled Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx). Or, as Gijo suggested, you could look at [database replication](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/database-replication), but I am not sure that you need that kind of overhead if you can get away with the first choice of periodically caching the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try replication. With replication, you can set to populate a certain table to get data from a stored procedure and then use this table to show the graph.